# Should I delete cache with a timer or?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I’ve got a simple question

I made an application similar to instagram, the only difference is that it has more stories&posts because there’s no following system.

I do cache the images and videos, but should I delete the caches with a timer?

It is lots of videos and images.

---

Or is it enough to cache and when terminating the app clear the caches

Comment: its depends on your requirement Instagram has its own cache  library for storing and managing  the content for different users   , if more then one user login into the app without terminating the app  then what you doing at the moment  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using standard caching mechanisms like `NSCache`, the OS will automatically clean it when it needs more memory for other applications. You don't need to worry about cleaning cache manually, unless you need some app specific behaviour.

Comment: For videos I use the following code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41551215/is-it-possible-to-cache-videos-ios-swift

Comment: And for images I use SdWebImage

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, SDWebImage makes use of NSCache exactly.