# AVPlayer cause TableView To Lag

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview, avplayer

I have to play video in my App inside tableView cell. According to view Screen size my Table Can show 2 cell in small screen device and 3 cell in large screen device like iPhone XSMax or Xr

**Flow**
`AVPlayerController` Class Created

```
class CustomAVPlayerViewController: AVPlayerViewController {
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        print("touchesBegan")
    }
}
```

Instances Created in cell class

```
var myImgArray=[String]()
    var myVideoArray=[String]()
    var myVideoPlayer : AVPlayer?
    var videoPlayerController : CustomAVPlayerViewController?
    var myPlayerItems=[AVPlayerItem]()
```

Prepare for Reuse Functions

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
        myVideoPlayer?.replaceCurrentItem(with: nil)
        videoPlayerController=nil
        myVideoPlayer=nil
        self.count=0
        myPlayerItems.removeAll()
        myImgArray.removeAll()
        myVideoArray.removeAll()
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime)
        for vieww in myScrollView.subviews {
            vieww.removeFromSuperview()
        }

    }
```

I am using `AVPLayer` instance one for a cell. A single cell can contain multiple videos so used an scrollview for that

```
if !videoArray.isEmpty {
            /// We've Videos
            for i in 0..<videoArray.count {
                ///Get Origin
                let xOrigin : CGFloat = CGFloat(i) * myScrollView.frame.size.width + (CGFloat(imgArray.count)*myScrollView.frame.size.width)
                let newPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: URL(string: videoArray[i])!)
                myPlayerItems.append(newPlayerItem)
                if i == 0 {
                    self.myVideoPlayer=AVPlayer(playerItem: newPlayerItem)
                    self.videoPlayerController = CustomAVPlayerViewController()
                    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime)
                    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.playerDidFinishPlaying(note:)), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: self.myVideoPlayer!.currentItem)
                    self.videoPlayerController?.player = self.myVideoPlayer!
                    self.videoPlayerController?.view.frame = CGRect(x: xOrigin+10, y: 10, width: self.myScrollView.frame.size.width-20, height: self.myScrollView.frame.size.height-20)
                    self.myVideoPlayer?.play()
                    myScrollView.addSubview(self.videoPlayerController!.view)
                    myScrollView.bringSubviewToFront(self.videoPlayerController!.view)
                }
            }
        }
```

As shown In above code I am looping through Video Array and adding its subview in scrollView

**Issue** -

it start to lag when there are multiple cell on screen which have video
or Next cell to be loaded which have video

I am using `prepareForReuse` to avoid High Memory Usage.
App cycles unto 40 MB in run of 4 Min which include other Features too

What I can do ?

**Tried Things**

1. Checking `IndexPathForVisibleCell` it include three cell which are displayed as soon as my cell goes off screen I remove scrollView subviews and AVPLayer instance.
2. Using Global `AVPLayer` Instance but didn't worked. It doesn't play video
   Reason - When three cell are on screen it won't be dequeued again so Video won't be loaded as global instance will be added in one only and prepareForReuse cause no video to play

Comment: It lags because every time you scroll the video must be loaded up. I think you need to cache the videos and if you could proccess them asynchronously that would be good aswell: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41551215/is-it-possible-to-cache-videos-ios-swift

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may lag because you add and remove the AVPlayer view.
Instead of removing them, you can reuse them so you can update the link when the cell is visible on screen.
You can refer any article like this: [Best way to check if UITableViewCell is completely visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9831485/best-way-to-check-if-uitableviewcell-is-completely-visible)

Comment: Where should I be calling this ? cellForRow isn't a good option. Can you please suggest

Comment: You can take a look on tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: Just a minor suggestion please. as soon I write myPlayer?.play() it cause tableview to lag very little now. Like flicker. Any idea how I can do that ?

Comment: You can put a delay, example after the cell appear on the screen more than one second, you will start playing. Otherwise, don't do anything.

Comment: Its like using DispatchQueue.asyncAfter() ? and it that again check for visible Index ?

Comment: That's one of solutions. You should put a delay before playing video since user scroll very fast and they just stop when they found the right video so that's time for you to handle playing the video on the visible cell.