# Swift 5 play video from local cache

Tags: swift, caching, video, avplayer

I am trying to reduce the data consumption of my app. Thats why I implemented the following caching for videos in my tableviewCells

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45062989/7186851

It works so far, that I can check whether the video is in my cache or not but I am unable to play it from my local cache

the cached video path looks something like this

```
file:/Users/Dev1/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/86AFC4DE-CA7F-4AA4-97EE-0FB17173D5A4/data/Containers/Data/Application/697F3F33-A87A-4CDD-A1D0-D124A8CA5593/Library/Caches/-MV8TA8hReegG2OIUyy0 -- file:///
```

When trying to play the video in the AVPlayer it won't work.

```
            CacheManager.shared.getFileWith(stringUrl: vUrl) { result in

                switch result {
                case .success(let newUrl):
                    uri = URL(fileURLWithPath: newUrl.absoluteString)
                   // let url = URL(string: uri)
                    print(uri)
                    self.player = AVPlayer(url: uri)
                    self.playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.player)
                    self.playerLayer?.frame = self.postImageView.frame
                    self.contentView.layer.addSublayer(self.playerLayer!)
                case .failure(_):
                    uri = URL(string: vUrl)
                }
            }
```

i start the video playing afterwards. It works perfectly fine when I download my videos from my cloudStorage, but I am unable to play the cached videos.

Any suggestions how to do it?
I have a similar video feed to tiktok/instagram&fb if this helps.

Comment: if `newUrl` is already a URL, why are you trying to make *another* URL object out of it by calling `URL(fileURLWithPath)`? Why not just pass `newURL` straight to the AVPlayer?

Comment: yeah this was unnecessary but still doesn't change anything

Comment: hey did you manage to solve this issue?

Comment: I saved the videos in userDefaults for the session :)