# Experience with saving Video's to Cache for offline usage

Tags: swift, caching

I am presently working on a video app and i am trying to apply cache to a download button for each video..

this is what i have tried

I have followed this link for implementation

[Is it possible to cache Videos? IOS - Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41551215/is-it-possible-to-cache-videos-ios-swift)

But after on success!!! video is not playing and not working for offline usage

pls can anyone direct me on what I am doing wrong?
I am a newbie

thanks